# How to hoist hot tub out of surrounding deck?

Tags: deck, woodworking, hot-tub

I need to raise a hot tub out of the deck in our back yard to address a critter problem (rodents have been living underneath so I need to clean it and critter-proof it.) The deck seems to have been built around the hot tub and it doesn't seem possible to disassemble the deck in a non-destructive way, so I'd like to hoist the hot tub directly upwards. Currently there is 23" of hot tub above the deck and 20" below the deck, resting on concrete. There is maybe 2" of clearance between the sides of the hot tub and the deck.

What I have in mind is to build a gantry crane similar to [this gentleman's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtPU1pOTLH4), rent two half-ton chain hoists to hang from the crane on either side of the hot tub, then raise it up and support it with wood braces or cinder blocks while I work on it, or possibly flip it on its side on top of the deck. Afterwards I would use the hoists to lower it back into place.

Because I'm hoping not to have to do this again, I'd like to avoid investing too much in disposable lumber and hardware. I was thinking of using 4x4s for the vertical posts, 2x6s for the horizontal support at the top, and 2x4s for the diagonal supports. To secure these pieces together I would use lag bolts with washers and nuts.

Does this plan make sense? I have fairly limited woodworking experience. What size of bolts would be sufficient? I was thinking 1/2" but they are somewhat expensive and I expect may be overkill. Here are a couple drawings of what I have in mind (front and side view):

[image: gantry crane with hot tub in raised position]

[image: side view of vertical support]

*Edit 1:*

Here is a photo of the hot tub with some of the surrounding deck boards removed:

[image: hot tub with partially exposed deck]

I am guessing the hot tub weighs something like 800 lbs, plus or minus 200.

The double 2x6 support resting on top of the tub in the picture above was slid out of the hangers built in to the deck; I imagine it was built that way to allow for easy access to the motor on that side. The other joists surrounding the tub are not easily removable. If I'm unable to lift the tub out I think I would need to disassemble and rebuild that entire portion of the deck which is about 14x14' including several steps.

To connect the tub to the hoist I was thinking of using screw eyes in the wood at the base of the tub. I haven't really figured that part out yet, so my drawing is a bit misleading.

Another consideration: I don't know if I will be successful at critter-proofing the thing on my first attempt, which is partly why I'd like to build a reusable crane in case I need to do this again 6 months from now (as opposed to destroying and rebuilding the deck multiple times)

*Edit 2:*

Some more photos:

[image: wide view of deck and hot tub]

[image: corner with deck boards removed]

[image: looking down at deck joists]

[image: clearance between joists and tub]

[image: looking down at motor area]

[image: looking into motor area]

[image: electrical connection]

Comment: Do you have any idea how much the tub weighs?

Comment: How are you going to attach the hot tub to the crane?  What's the hot tub made of?

Comment: really need a picture of the tub and deck. the crane and midevil drawing is not helping you find a good answer.

Comment: Plumbing connections?

Comment: What is the deck made of? Can the deck support the weight of the gantry and hot tub? I'd think so only iff it is a wood or concrete deck. If it is wood, you'd be better off figuring out how to remove the decking and work on the tub in situ. Attaching the tub to the crane will be the most difficult. It isn't like the hot tub has lift points you can hook into. You'd have to slip straps underneath the hot tub. You'll need to do some extra tricky rigging to balance everything and keep the straps from crushing the sides inward. Post pictures of the deck and tub.

Comment: Whatever solution you go with, "overkill" in construction and support is better than "kill you" in execution. A few bucks (even a few hundred) is better than hospital bills or loss of life. Even if the tub isn't _that_ heavy, if something fails, it could be deadly.

Comment: *"kill you" in execution* Interesting choice of words...

Comment: If somebody said to me, *I can't figure out how to remove deck boards, so I'm going to improvise my own hot tub lift, and use the cheapest bolts I can to do it,* I would ask that person to seriously reconsider their entire plan, and suggest they get an insured handyman or pest control service to help with the problem.  That's what I'm suggesting to you now.  Your plan is a danger to your life and property.  Be safe, friend!  Post some pics and maybe we can help you work out how to access the tub area for cleaning without removing it.

Comment: Did a bit of googling on empty hot tub weight and from what I read they average around 500 lbs so I think what you have in mind is probably fine as long as the structure around it can support around 250 on each side and the center rail can bear the full weight if it falls into the average.

Comment: @SteveSether I was planning to hoist by adding screw eyes to the wooden supports at the base of the tub. Tub itself is some kind of plastic.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact No plumbing connections. There is an electrical cable that seems to have lots of slack, hardwired to a breaker box about 10-15' away.

Comment: Definitely disconnect the cable, at whichever end is easiest.

Comment: @JeffWheeler thanks for the advice! I have hired pest control, and contacted the hot tub manufacturer and our local hot tub service people and none have been super helpful. I could probably find a carpenter to help but I don't know what they might do differently (except be more skilled at disassembling and reassembling the deck joists), and I doubt they want to deal with rat droppings any more than I do! Removing the deck boards was no problem.

Comment: @gosko I'd be concerned about the thing just coming apart, coming unbalanced, etc.  You're focused on the lifting mechanism, but you also need to focus on how the thing is going to resist gravity.  I'd tend to agree with the people advising extreme caution, and getting professional help.

Comment: @SteveSether I agree, that's the weakest part of the plan, in my mind. I had thought the chain hoists seem slow and gentle enough that I can see what happens as tension increases and adjust or reposition as needed. I asked our local hot tub service place for help and they said for $900 they could lift it using inflatable air bags but after checking it out on site they said there isn't enough clearance to position the air bags underneath.

Comment: Is part of the tub resting directly on a concrete slab; and part of it has a gap/void underneath?  It's a little tough to tell, but is that where you think the critters are living?  I would think about putting some pea gravel or sand under there (or whatever pest control person suggests in your area) to discourage future infestation (while allowing water to drain freely.)  I'd also demo that step for better access and just re-assemble/rebuild it afterward, if being able to reach under the tub there will help.

Comment: I added some more photos. It seems to have a plywood base, sitting on concrete. There is a fair bit of space above the plywood for critters to run around once they have access, and they have eaten away at the insulation and left urine and droppings everywhere. I cleaned up as much as I could with a shop vac but can't reach everywhere, only the two sides that I managed to open. The pest control guy said I should get rid of as much insulation as possible since it has their scent and will attract others. I'd like to seal the whole thing up with hardware mesh or something before lowering it again.

Comment: It looks like you can keep removing decking and joists as much as you need to access the tub cabinet, and re-assemble everything easily!  Number the bottom of the boards and where they were on the joists, if you like, to make it more likely everything fits nicely when you're finished.  If you struggle with re-using screw holes or anything, try flipping the joists over or replace them.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ax_I41uUF90.   Notice the rigging here

Comment: @JeffWheeler I'd like to have access to the entire bottom and sides of the tub so I can fully inspect and critter-proof it.

Comment: Well, the basic problem with a lift in your situation is, how to get lifting straps under the tub.  You're going to have to do at least some additional demo to get straps under it.  I suppose you can leave the straps there for future use.  I know you suggested adding lifting eyes to the tub but they're not designed to be moved that way; the result would be a wrecked tub.

Answer (score 5):

I'd be cautious building something like this with limited woodworking experience. Typical framing like this would have 1/2" bolts and your rough sketch is similar to other stable gantries.
I see this a lot in Florida where people have partially below grade hot tubes and need to raise them for drain and piping replacement. Renting a gantry seems to be the popular way to do this. Some with wheels on the base allow you to move it out of the way to do your work. See picture below. This might save you some time and keep you from having to build one yourself.

[image]

I have no business interest in any rental companies.

Comment: Thanks – this might be a good option, but the closest place I could rent it from is a 2-hr drive each way, and it would cost about $300/week. I figure I can build one myself for about $100, and be able to reuse it in the future or disassemble it and reuse the lumber and hardware. The homemade version in the video I linked looks fairly straightforward.